# Add a Join in Magento with SQL query as the table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a query like this =>

```
select table1.id, table1.name,
sorted_table2.marks from table1 LEFT JOIN (select DISTINCT student_id, marks from table2  order by marks DESC ) sorted_table2 ON table1.id = sorted_table2.student_id;
```

How can I convert this to magento?

```
  $select->joinLeft( array('sorted_table2' => '(select DISTINCT student_id, marks from table2 orderby marks DESC AS sorted_table2)'),'table1.id = sorted_table2.student_id', '*');
```

This doesn't work, as it addes "`" to the query and treats it like a table name. Is there a way I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Your raw MySQL code won't even compile.  Please include your current working code.

Comment: ORDER BY in subquery makes no sense - it will be ignored in outer query.

Comment: Order by is used, so that it gives me the row with highest marks from table2.